# How can I read a java property file and get its values?

Tags: java, properties

In Ruby I have a **sample.yml** file as below,

```
1_Group1:
   path:asdf
   filename:zxcv

2_Group2:
  path:qwer
  filename:poiu
etc etc............
```

Now I need to have **Example.properties** file Java, which should contains data as above.

Using Java, I want to read the **Example.properties** file.

Then need to iterate the contents based on the number of groups and get the corresponding "path" and "filename" values.

For eg: If there are 5 groups.. Group1,Group2....Group5
Then I need to iterate

```
      for(int i=0; i< noofgroups(5);i++){
            ........................
           String slave =  aaa.getString("path");
            aaa.getString("filename");
        }
```

Like this I need to get each path and filename.

Now I have **Example.properties** as follws,

```
   path:asdf
   filename:zxcv
```

It is working (I can read and get the values)

But I need to have may keys as "path" and " fileneame". SO I need to group them.

Comment: I can read that file and retrieve what I need now. But I need to have 3 or 4 keys as "path" and "filename". SO that I raised the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `yaml` format, you can find out a [yamlbeans](http://code.google.com/p/yamlbeans/)

You can using it like this:

```
YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader("sample.yml"));
Map map = (Map)reader.read();
System.out.println(map.get("1_Group1"));
```

Comment: Thanks. But we cann't do this using sample.properties ?

Comment: @Prince yes, you can't, for `sample.properties` use a `java.util.Properties`

Comment: Yes already I'm using java.util.Properties. But I dn't know how to use it for my case

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to go about this; the most natural might be to use a naturally-hierarchical format, like YAML, JSON, or XML.

Another option is to use one of the [Commons Configuration hierarchical configs](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_xml.html#Hierarchical_properties) techniques like a [hierarchical INI style](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/HierarchicalINIConfiguration.html).

If you want to use a "pure" property file I'd suggest just reading in your properties, splitting the property names on periods, and storing to a map or class, so you'd have:

```
1_Group1.path=asdf
1_Group1.filename:zxcv

2_Group2.path=qwer
2_Group2.filename=poiu
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.utils.Properties` in the following way:

```
public static void loadPropertiesAndParse() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    String propsFilename = "path_to_props_file";
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(propsFilename);
    props.load(in);
    Enumeration en = props.keys();
    while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        String tmpValue = (String) en.nextElement();
        String path = tmpValue.substring(0, tmpValue.lastIndexOf(File.separator)); // Get the path
        String filename = tmpValue.substring(tmpValue.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1, tmpValue.length()); // Get the filename
    }
}
```

And your `properties` file will look like this:

```
key_1=path_with_file_1
key_2=path_with_file_2
```